# Serial port receives same bytes it just sent

Tags: c++, serial-port, boost-asio, cat

I'm trying to use Boost.Asio to read from and write to a serial port. Here is my code:

```
void async_read(boost::asio::serial_port& serial_port)
{
    auto buffer = std::make_shared<std::vector<uint8_t>>(64);
    serial_port.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(*buffer),
            [buffer, &serial_port](const boost::system::error_code& error, size_t bytes_read)
            {
                if (error)
                {
                    std::cout << "Error reading serial port: " << error.message() << std::endl;
                    return;
                }
                std::string message(buffer->begin(), buffer->end());
                std::cout << "Read " << bytes_read << " bytes:\t" << message << std::endl;
                async_read(serial_port);
            });
}

void async_write(boost::asio::serial_port& serial_port)
{
    auto timer = std::make_shared<boost::asio::deadline_timer>(serial_port.get_io_service(), boost::posix_time::seconds(1));
    timer->async_wait(
            [&serial_port, timer](const boost::system::error_code& error)
            {
                if (error)
                {
                    std::cout << "Timer error: " << error.message() << std::endl;
                    return;
                }

                auto message = std::make_shared<std::string>("Hello\n");
                boost::asio::async_write(serial_port, boost::asio::buffer(*message),
                        [message, &serial_port](const boost::system::error_code& error, size_t bytes_sent)
                        {
                            if (error)
                            {
                                std::cout << "Error writing to serial port: " << error.message() << std::endl;
                                return;
                            }
                            std::cout << "Wrote " << bytes_sent << " bytes" << std::endl;
                            async_write(serial_port);
                        });
            });
}

int main()
{
    boost::asio::io_service service;
    auto serial_port = boost::asio::serial_port(service, "/dev/ttyUSB0");
    serial_port.set_option(boost::asio::serial_port::baud_rate(9600));
    async_read(serial_port);
    async_write(serial_port);
    service.run();
}
```

At the opposite end of the serial cable, I have a separate machine running `cat /dev/ttyTHS0`.
**My issue** is that whenever the program performs an `async_write`, those same bytes are immediately handled by the `async_read` completion handler - even though the remote machine isn't sending anything.

I'm not sure if the root cause is the code, or because I'm using `cat` at the other end. When `cat` is not running, I'm not having the issue.

Running the above code, (with `cat /dev/ttyTHS0` at the other end) gives output like this:

```
Wrote 6 bytes
Read 7 bytes:   Hello

Wrote 6 bytes
Read 3 bytes:   Hel
Read 4 bytes:   lo

Wrote 6 bytes
Read 7 bytes:   Hello

Wrote 6 bytes
Read 1 bytes:   H
Read 6 bytes:   ello

Wrote 6 bytes
Read 7 bytes:   Hello
```

Maybe I'm missing something obvious, but any help is appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: What protocol is being used? RS 485, for example, uses the same wires for send and receive, so if you aren't careful, or the hardware isn't, everything you send will be echoed back at you.

Comment: @user4581301 Thanks for your response! I honestly don't know. How can I check for that?

Comment: After posting this question, I tried another approach where I wrote a separate Boost.Asio program at the receving end. Using that, I was not having the same issue. Even stranger, after running that, the issue went away when I tried `cat` again. I think boost must be doing some configuration that I'm unaware of.

Comment: Smurfed if I know. depends on the hardware. If the cable you are using only has two wires, that's a pretty good sign of RS-485. Looks like you have a *nix system. See what happens with minicom. If you get the same behaviour with it, it ain't your software. It could be a bug in your code, but that bug might just be something you don't know you have to do like toggle the RTS line to turn off the receiver while transmitting. Probably time to dive into the documentation for your device and the doo-dad it's talking to for more information.

Comment: The cable has 3 wires for ground, Tx, and Rx. I _think_ it's using UART, but I'm not certain.

Comment: I wouldn't expect a hardware echo if they're separated RX and TX. If it's not using a UART you'd be working a lot harder. `cat` should echo what's read to stdout. What is the  other side? is stdout a serial port echoed to a serial port? what happens if you replace `cat` with `minicom` or something similar? What happens if you write to stdout on the other end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the expected behaviour for a serial port. These were typically used to connect a terminal like a vt100 to a computer. When you type on the keyboard, the character is sent to the computer, and the serial port echoes it back to the vt100 screen where it is displayed.

If you run `stty -a -F /dev/ttyTHS0` on the remote you will see the setting `echo` is on (before you ran your program on the remote). You can switch it off with `stty -echo -F /dev/ttyTHS0`, when it will show as `-echo`.

Typically, when serial ports are used for comms between computers, the application will set the port to *raw, noecho*. This is to avoid certain translations being done by the serial port driver, so the data arrives unchanged at the application.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The issue mysteriously went away when I switch from `cat` to another Boost.Asio program, but I was able to bring back the echo behavior by running `stty echo -F /dev/ttyTHS0` on the remote. I also verified the command you provided will disable the echo behavior.